# Can Adjust Android SDK be prevented from opening the relevant Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, deep-linking, adjust-android

I have been facing a problem related to Adjust deep links in my Android app.

I have an Adjust link in the following format:
https://app.adjust.com/of6d6ty?deep_link=myapp://account/register&fallback=https://www.myapp/de/mobile-app-page

The issue I'm encountering is that when I click this Adjust link, it opens the related Fragment inside my app twice. This double navigation is causing problems for me.

The first navigation is initiated immediately by Adjust, and I am unable to interfere or stop it. After I press the back button to navigate back, the second navigation is handled by me in the **onResume** method of the Activity via **intent.dataString**, and the related Fragment opens for the second time.

I want to handle all deep links manually so that I can perform some checks before navigation, such as determining whether the user needs to log in or change their country.

I attempted to disable the relevant code blocks inside my **App.kt** file, which includes the following lines:

```
val environment = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) AdjustConfig.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX else AdjustConfig.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION
Adjust.onCreate(AdjustConfig(this, BuildConfig.ADJUST_APP_TOKEN, environment))
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(adjustListener)
```

The **adjustListener** class is defined as follows:

```
class AdjustLifecycleCallback : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}
    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        Adjust.onResume()
    }
    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
        Adjust.onPause()
    }
    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {}
    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {}
    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {}
}
```

Even when I commented out these code blocks, Adjust still opened the related Fragment again upon clicking the Adjust link.

However, I noticed that when I removed the  tags from the **navigation_graph.xml** file, like in the following example:

```
<deepLink
    android:autoVerify="true"
    app:uri="myapp://account/register" />
```

Adjust was unable to open the related Fragment. This achieved what I wanted, preventing Adjust from opening the Fragment. However, **I need these  tags** for certain cases within the app.

Is there any way to disable Adjust from navigating to the related Fragment without commenting out the  tags? I'm looking for a solution that allows me to manually handle deep link navigation and perform necessary checks while still using the  tags when needed.